# How to add values from mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code but it displays two different sum of values.
I have total with per row and it has 2 value 100 and 200 .
it displays 100 and 200 seperately.
But i want the sum of 100 and 200 .
sum= 300
 how could i do it?

```
$result2 = mysql_query("select * from price  where dom='$cat'",$db);
while ($myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    echo $myrow2["totalwithper"];
}
```

here is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `price` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dom` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `etiket` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `pricestandart` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `totalunper` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `discount` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `totalwithper` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `price`
--

INSERT INTO `price` (`id`, `dom`, `etiket`, `pricestandart`, `number`, `totalunper`, `discount`, `totalwithper`) VALUES
(18, 'Alten Group', 'flayer', 100, 1, 100, 10, 90),
(19, 'Alten Group', 'logo', 100, 2, 200, 15, 170);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $result2 = mysql_query ("select sum(totalwithper) from price  where dom='$cat'",$db);
  $myrow2= mysql_fetch_array($result2);
  do{
     echo $myrow2["totalwithper"];
    }
    while($myrow2=mysql_fetch_array($result2));
```

a small rewrite to your code :

```
 $result2 = mysql_query ("select sum(totalwithper) from price  where dom='$cat'",$db);
 while($myrow2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
         echo $myrow2["totalwithper"];
        }
```

sum by loop

```
 $sum=0;
 $result2 = mysql_query ("select totalwithper from price  where dom='$cat'",$db);
 while($myrow2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
         $sum=$sum+ $myrow2["totalwithper"];
        }

 echo "sum : $sum";
```

In $sum you will get the sum.

Comment: If you fix the indenting and remove the useless blank lines it will look even nicer :-)

Comment: thank all of you But now it doesnt give any result. do u have any idea? or how could use loop get all values from fetch array then adding up them? what you think?

Comment: ali can you share your table structure

Comment: i posted table structure at the top of page where i asked question.

Comment: are you looking for the sum of `totalunper`

Comment: totalwithper. neither of them works. if totalunper works then totalwithper has to work either. but doesnt. do you know any other way to solve this problem if so write me back . thank you

Comment: it works now thank u a lot. i wrote it at the top of this page. u might not see that. u helped me a lot. i used second way with loop. it  would be a website its web application to count prices incomes discounts.and it will work in localhost. thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent the last couple of days trying to make the `array_sum()` function work and it would print out every number but wouldn't add them together. But with this code it finally worked for me TY.

```
 $sum=0;
 $result2 = mysql_query ("select totalwithper from price  where dom='$cat'",$db);
 while($myrow2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
 {
    $sum=$sum+ $myrow2["totalwithper"];
 }

 echo "sum : $sum";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Sum(totalwithper) FROM price  WHERE ...
```

see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("select sum(totalwithper) from price  where dom='$cat'",$db);
```

Comment: @parvin: in quesion 'Ali Shikhiyev' has mentioned as `total with per` row